# async for loop in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am looking at very interesting site here
https://faust.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ and I am amazed at this piece of code:

```
class Order(faust.Record):
    account_id: str
    product_id: str
    price: float
    quantity: float = 1.0

orders_topic = app.topic('orders', key_type=str, value_type=Order)

@app.agent(orders_topic)
async def process_order(orders):
    async for order in orders:
        # process each order using regular Python
        total_price = order.price * order.quantity
        await send_order_received_email(order.account_id, order)
```

My question how is the `async for order in orders` even working ?
What version of Python introduced this kind of syntax ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was implemented in Python 3.5:

https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/#asynchronous-iterators-and-async-for

> Python-Version:   3.5
>
> An asynchronous iterable is able to call asynchronous code in its iter implementation, and asynchronous iterator can call asynchronous code in its next method.

Comment: Thank You Selcuk this is really neat